# Dimensions of second order derivatives

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In real life applications, let say I have $dT/dx$ where $T$ is temperature and $x$ is distance (could be fahrenheit, centimeters)

So the units of $dT/dx$ are $F/cm$, but what about $d^2T/dt^2$? The second derivative?

How can I do a fractional analysis like I did with $dT/dx$?

Comment: The unit of $\mathrm{d}^2T/\mathrm{d}t^2$ is $\mathrm{F}/\mathrm{cm}^2$, or better $\mathrm{K}/\mathrm{m}^2$. It is like with the derivative of a distance function: $s(t)$ might have unit $\mathrm{m}$. $\mathrm{d}s/\mathrm{d}t$ is velocity, hence unit is $\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$. And $\mathrm{d}^2s/\mathrm{d}t^2$ is acceleration hence has unit $\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$.